# Is there a way to sync WhatsApp profile photos with Contacts Photos?

Tags: big-sur, whatsapp.app, contacts.app

I would like to know if there is a way to automatically sync the profile pics that people set in their WhatsApp profile to the contacts photos in my Contacts app on OS X (Big Sur).

Comment: Probably 'no'.  WhatsApp does not have an AppleScript interface so would likely need some mouse clicking and screen scraping to do it - Keyboard Maestro perhaps.